# OpenCV 3.1 iOS can't load classifier from .xml

Tags: ios, xml, opencv, opencv3.1

I'm trying to run this example on iOS:
https://github.com/egeorgiou/openCViOSFaceTrackingTutorial

Everything works except this function:

```
faceCascade.detectMultiScale(grayscaleFrame, faces, 1.1, 2, HaarOptions, cv::Size(60, 60));
```

I get an error like this:

```
error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale
```

I read a bit about it and everyone is saying that the problem is that the faceCascade is not being loaded. 
At the moment I load it like this:

```
NSString* faceCascadePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"haarcascade_frontalface_alt2" ofType:@"xml"];
self.faceCascade.load([faceCascadePath UTF8String]);
```

How should I load the `.xml` file so it works correctly? Or maybe should I put the `haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml` file somewhere else in XCode? 
I'm using Xcode 8.

Comment: use full path ...

Comment: @Miki this did not help :/ I changed the pathForResource like this:
`/Users/John/Documents/Projects/OpenCVTest/OpenCVTest/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2` but still not working :(

Comment: Did you add `.xml` at the end. Also to get exact filepath, just drop the file in terminal and it will show you the filepath.